# Meaning of "having a high game"

Tags: idioms, colloquial-language

I know that there is an idiom "being at the top of their game".

I wanted to know if this sentence makes any sense-Everybody here has a high emoji game. It's referring to people on a certain social media group having a way with emojis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Having a **high** X game" does not sound idiomatic to this US English speaker.  We usually say someone's game is **strong**, not *high*.

For example,

- [7 Tips to Keep Your Selfie Game Strong](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-and-solutions/7-tips-keep-your-selfie-game-strong)
- [This Actor’s Cartoon Game Is Strong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpgnMeDjnO8) (although this is also a pun on the fact that her last name is "Strong")
- [My Girl Scout Cookie Game is STRONG](https://www.girlscoutshop.com/GSNorCal-My-Girl-Scout-Cookie-Game-is-STRONG-T-Shirt)

---

We should note that this use of *strong* is very recent, slangy, and informal.  This is probably OK if you are talking about a group of friends using emoji, but I would not use it in a formal paper.

Comment: "Everyone here has a strong emoji game". Does this sound correct to you?

Comment: @Crux: No, I wouldn't say it's particularly idiomatic to say someone ***has a strong game*** in the first place (except *maybe* just about, if you're talking about their skill at playing tennis or chess, for example). And metaphorically switching the meaning to ***skill at using emojis*** (as a *game?*) doesn't work at all for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you please suggest me a better way to phrase the aforementioned sentence? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm curious to know why you think it isn't "particularly idiomatic to say someone *has a strong game*".  I did just cite three recent references using *strong X game*.

Comment: I originally searched for the sequence ***he has a strong game*** in Google Book - it only returned 3-4 hits anyway, and they were mostly in the context of playing contract bridge (where "game" has a highly context-specific meaning).  But the clincher for me is comparing [***has / plays** a strong game {of something}*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+a+strong+game+of%2Cplays+a+strong+game+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplays%20a%20strong%20game%20of%3B%2Cc0) in Google Books, where ***to have*** simply doesn't occur enough to chart.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the thing is probably that "has a strong X game" is very recent and slangy, and therefore unlikely to show up in books.  I'm going to edit my comment to reflect that.

Comment: Okay, I'm convinced. But I suspect that *as a relatively new usage*, "having" a strong game might be primarily American at the moment. (Or perhaps I just don't talk to the right people! :)